# How to solve Error: RPCError -503: Timedout (caused by SaveBigFilePartRequest) telethon send file error

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

When sending big files with

```
await client.send_file(channel_id, file_name, thumb=thumbnail, caption=caption, attributes=[types.DocumentAttributeVideo(duration=video_duration, w=0, h=0, supports_streaming=True)], mime_type='video/mp4')
```

I often run into the error `Error: RPCError -503: Timedout (caused by SaveBigFilePartRequest)`

At present I modified the code so that each time the error is encountered the script will try to send the file again which works fine. But is there any way to avoid the error completely? What changes should i make to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can solve. A negative error in Telegram acts like an HTTP status code, and the 500 range stands for "internal server errors".

This is a server-side error on Telegram's part and cannot be fixed or worked around by Telethon or other libraries.

The only solution is to wait for them to resolve it on their end.